401 Error With REST API Request
This is probably dumb on my part, but I've been trying to figure out this GET Request using a users session id. I will admit chatGPT has gotten me this far and I've hit a wall. I can get this to work in Postman but not in my code. I'm certain it's something to do with how I'm formatting the request, but any insight would help.
    // Construct the API URL
    const apiUrl = `${domain}/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Account/${recordId}`;
    console.log("API URL:", apiUrl);

    // Make the API call using the session ID
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionId}`,
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Host': `${domain}`
        },
    });

Error Message I get:

POSTMAN configuration:


https://jsforce.github.io

I'm surprised the lightning.force.com domain works for Postman, since that's mainly the domain of the Lightning UI.  In general, all API calls to Salesforce should use your my.salesforce.com domain.

Adding to David Cheng's observation, may I ask: What do you mean by "using a users session id"? You don't mean a session ID a user got in a Lightning context? This can't work. Are you testing the two ways (Postman, Javascript) utilizing the same way to get a suitable session ID?

Essentially I'm attempting to replicate the way the "Salesforce Inspector" chrome extension manages auth. Which from what I could tell is retrieving the session id from the users browsers cookies. Then using the session id for api requests.

To connect Salesforce via a 3rd party application (like Postman or else) you shouldn't rely on a browser cookie. Cause your code should be able to work from anywhere. With or without a session to Salesforce UI initiated.
As part of the transaction you must authenticate first to Salesforce. One way is a post reqest  using :

a generic endpoint, e.g. test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com, passing ClientId, ClientSecret (from a connectedApp created inside Salesforce) and user / password+ security token (there are other mechanisms)
Salesforce will send you back in the response an access token and an instance url => You use the access token after Bearer in your example AND you use the instance Url provided by Salesforce. Though it might now work with xxxx.lightningforce.com a) Salesforce may change their domains/dns (they did that 1 1/2 years ago) or b) you want your code to work with other environments (like scratch org, live, etc... and they might be different)

{
"access_token": "*******************",
"instance_url": "https://yourInstance.salesforce.com",
"token_type": "Bearer"
}


I got it to work using jsforce and getting the session Id from the browser cookies. Code is sheit, but it works so hopefully thats helpful.
(async function () {
try {
    const sessionId = await getSessionId(host); // Retrieve the session ID
    console.log("SessionID: " + sessionId);
    const instanceUrl = "https://XXXX.salesforce.com";

    // Construct the API URL
    const apiUrl = `https://${host}/services/data/v62.0/sobjects/Account/${recordId}`;
    console.log("API URL:", apiUrl);

    const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
      instanceUrl: instanceUrl,
      accessToken: sessionId
    });

    const res = conn.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.Stringify(res, null, 2))
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error during API call:", error);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
    document.getElementById("recordName").textContent = "Error fetching record details.";
}})()

Here's how to get the sessionID
async function getSessionId(targetDomain) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get all cookies named "sid"
    chrome.cookies.getAll({ name: "sid" }, (cookies) => {
        if (cookies && cookies.length > 0) {
            // Find the cookie with the matching domain
            const validCookie = cookies.find(cookie => cookie.domain === targetDomain);
            if (validCookie) {
                resolve(validCookie.value); // Return the session ID
            } else {
                reject(`No sid cookie found for domain: ${targetDomain}`);
            }
        } else {
            reject("No sid cookies found.");
        }
    });
});}

Then adding this tag to the HTML file
<script src="/node_modules/jsforce/dist/jsforce.min.js"></script>

